# Suckless Surf Browser not rendering webpages correctly

Tags: raspberry-pi, yocto

I created an image for my RPI4 using Yocto and BitBake. I also added Suckless Surf browser that runs on X11 and openbox. Even though I am able to open the browser and browse to websites, the content within the browser window is not getting rendered correctly. Based on the color schemes of various websites, you can see that it is loading the websites, but displaying them incorrectly. (Almost like a distorted puzzle that was put together in an incorrect order).  Everything else on the desktop (e.g. xTerm) looks normal. I don't find any error logs that could point me into the right direction, so I was hoping someone no here could give me some pointers. Unfortunately, I don't have a lot of experience when it comes to GUIs, so any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.